# Compile a coffeescript file and output in multiple folders

Tags: javascript, command-line, coffeescript

My structure is :

```
src/awesome.coffee
dist/
demo/
```

I want to compile `awesome.coffee` and output in `dist` and `demo` with the CLI of coffee.

Right now i'm doing that :

`coffee --compile --watch --output dist/ src/`

and I have no idea how to add a new output folder ...

Comment: are you bound to the cli? `grunt` or `gulp` might help you a great deal with that.

Comment: Will dist and demo have the same contents always? Can't one of them be a symlink? If not, you'll need to use a build system as @PatrickJ.S. recommended.